# Change the order of columns

Tags: r

I am working on a large dataframe with >40 columns.  I want to be able to move a column, without having to specify all the column names.  For example:

```
a<-c(1:5)  
b<-c(4,3,2,1,1)  
Percent<-c(40,30,20,10,10)
Labels<-c("Cat","Dog","Rabbit","Rat","Mouse")
df1<-data.frame(a,b,Percent,Labels)
```

How would I move the column 'Lables' to before column 'a' WITHOUT having to write all the other column names (i.e. can I just specify a column to come before/after another column?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something quick and dirty would be (i.e. no sanity checking etc. and assuming only a single `colname` is supplied):

```
moveToFirstCol <- function(df, colname) {
    cnams <- colnames(df)
    want <- which(colname == cnams)
    df[, c(cnams[want], cnams[-want])]
}
```

which gives:

```
> moveToFirstCol(df1, "Labels")
  Labels a b Percent
1    Cat 1 4      40
2    Dog 2 3      30
3 Rabbit 3 2      20
4    Rat 4 1      10
5  Mouse 5 1      10
```

That should suggest a way to handle this sort of thing if you need additional flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with additional flexibility:

```
move_variable <- function(x,where,data,after=FALSE){
 vnames <- names(data)
 x_idx <- match(x, vnames)
 where_idx <- match(where, vnames)
 idx <- seq(length(vnames))
 idx[x_idx] <- where_idx
 idx1 <- rep(0L, length(vnames))
 if(after) idx1[x_idx] <- 1 else idx1[where_idx] <- 1
 return(data[order(idx, idx1)])
}
```